# Bonus points after turning in contract for the second time

Tags: team-fortress-2

I completed a contract but missed some bonus points, so I did the contract again to get them all. Each time I turned in the contract after getting the bonus points, the number of stars I have didn't change. It showed me that it gave me a star, but my stars were unchanged (3).

Is there a limit to how many stars you can have at once, or this just bugged?

Edit: here are some screenshots before and after, except this time it was doing the contract *for the first time*:

1. [image: 1]
2. [image: 2]
3. [image: 3]
4. [image: 4]

It seems that it caps it at 3 stars, and throws away any stars over that amount. After I took the screenshots above, I bought the next sniper contract and then restarted TF2:

5. [image: 5]

Comment: I don't suppose you have before or after screenshots?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @chicks added screenshots since it happened again.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch contracts again, or relaunch TF2 with a new contract selected, the star count should update.

Contract updates not happening has been a problem for awhile, even after I've completely finished and maxed out all my contracts, I still get notifications saying 'contracts available' with the respective voice lines.

Comment: I haven't been able to even try this out, because now I can't even seem to make progress at all in order to get the stars (it doesn't register when I e.g. defend the objective for the defence contracts). It seems it's buggy as hell. I dunno why I'm surprised. What a waste of money.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info.